# Replace "a**b" to pow(a,b)

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math

For example, I have the following code:

```
import sympy as sp
t = sp.Symbol("t")
f = t**2
print(f)
```

Output: `t**2`

Can I get output `pow(t,2)`, using sympy?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to hack the string printer:

```
from sympy.printing import StrPrinter
StrPrinter._print_Pow = lambda self, expr: "pow(%s, %s)" % (self._print(expr.base), self._print(expr.exp))
```

That is, this overwrites the method `_print_Pow` in the class `StrPrinter`, which is responsible for printing the string form of `Pow` objects.